# change to a php variable in blade laravel doesn't persist

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-blade

When I increment `currentIndex` whenever I click the next button, the value of `currentIndex` returns to its default value which is 1 here. So the update of `currentIndex` doesn't persist. Does anyone have any idea why? And how can I solve this problem?

```
    let inputBoxNum = 3
    let currentIndex
    {{ $currentIndex = 1 }}
    updateButtons()
    $('.back-btn, .next-btn').on('click', function (e) {
        console.log({{$currentIndex}}) // returns 1 even if this function was called before
        let btnClicked = e.target.className.includes('next-btn') ? 'next' : 'back'
        if (btnClicked === 'next') {
            {{$currentIndex += 1}} // it increments to 2
            console.log({{$currentIndex}}) // returns 2
            $('#create-input-box').html(`@include('reservations.create-input-box-'.$currentIndex)`)
        } else {
            $('#create-input-box').html(`@include('reservations.create-input-box-'.$currentIndex)`)
        }
        updateButtons()
    })
    function updateButtons() {
        getCurrentIndex()
        if (currentIndex <= 1) {
            $('.back-btn').hide()
            $('.next-btn').show()
        } else if (currentIndex > 1 && currentIndex < inputBoxNum) {
            $('.back-btn').show()
            $('.next-btn').show()
        } else {
            $('.back-btn').show()
            $('.next-btn').hide()
        }
    }

    function getCurrentIndex() {
        currentIndex = parseInt($('#create-input-box')[0].children[0].className.split("-")[3])
    }
```

Comment: You are mixing Javascript with PHP... PHP is executed first (on the server side), the result (if you print it) is used on Javascript (executed on the client side = browser), but they do not "share" runtime...

Comment: is there an alternative to make this work? I just want to be able to pass some javascript to the include @matiaslauriti